# перемещение файлов Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть функция, которая возвращает URI файла, выбранного пользователем в виде "content://...", как по этому URI переместить файл в другую директорию?

Comment: В какую "другую" директорию? В Андроиде жесткие ограничения на хранение (доступ) файлов. При выборе файла уже возвращается content uri ничего преобразовывать не нужно.

Comment: Во внутреннюю директорию приложения. Я не говорю о преобразовании, мне необходимо переместить файл, зная его uri

Comment: Мне помог следующий ответ:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework)

Comment: Открываете URI как поток на чтение, читаете и пишете полученные данные куда угодно, хоть в файл, хоть в сеть. Тут важно понять одно: URI это не обьект файловой системы, физически может представлять из себя хоть BLOB в БД. Понятия "перемесить", "другая папка", "удалить" для него в общем смысле не применимы. Ответы, что вам говорите помогли, 2013-14 годов. Много воды утекло с того времени, не все может быть все еще актуальным.